# How to derive this identity for cylindric algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

I would like to show that the following identity holds for the cylindric algebras of dimension $n$:

> $c_i(x\vee y)\approx c_i(x)\vee c_i(y)$.

I can easily show that $c_i(x)\vee c_i(y)\leq c_i(x\vee y)$ for such algebras, but I am having trouble showing the converse.

As for $c_i(x)\vee c_i(y)\leq c_i(x\vee y)$, it follows from

$$c_i(x)\wedge c_i(x\vee y)\approx c_i(x\wedge c_i(x\vee y)),$$

as $x\leq x\vee y\leq c_i(x\vee y)$.

This is part of exercise 12 in Ch. 4, Section 1, in Burris and Sankappanavar's  *A Course in Universal Algebra*.

Comment: Did you make the other parts of the exercise? I have a proof of this which uses later parts of the same exercise, which I seem to have proved without using this one. But maybe there is a shorter proof...

Comment: I proved part (g) of this exercise using this part, unfortunately. I think the other ones (except (i)) didn't use this part for me.

Comment: Although I didn't read it thoroughly, it seems like I used parts (b), (f) and (g) (at least these ones are explicitly referred). If you have these parts proved too, I can give you the proof of this part (e).

Comment: Ah, I see now that you can prove (g) without (d). If you would like to give the proof of (d) then I would much appreciate it. I will definitely try to prove it myself though now that I know (g) is provable without (d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, let us recall that, according to that book, an $n$-dimensional cylindric algebra is an algebra
$$\mathbf A = (A,\vee,\wedge,',c_0,\ldots,c_{n-1},0,1,d_{00},d_{01},\ldots,d_{n-1,n-1})$$
such that $c_0,\ldots,c_{n-1}$ are unary, $d_{00},\ldots, d_{n-1,n-1}$ are nullary, $(A,\vee,\wedge,',0,1)$ is a Boolean algebra and, among other identities, it satisfies, for $i<n$,
\begin{equation}
\label{CA3}
x \leq c_i(x)
\tag{CA3}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\label{CA4}
c_i(x \wedge c_i(y)) = c_i(x) \wedge c_i(y).
\tag{CA4}
\end{equation}
The identity asked in the post is part (d) of the exercise, where the following are also included and can be proved (and apparently, were proved) without using (d):
\begin{align}
c_i(c_i(x)) &= c_i(x),  \label{b}\tag{b}\\
c_i((c_i(x))') &= (c_i(x))'. \label{g}\tag{g}
\end{align}

If $x \leq y$, then by \eqref{CA3}, $x \leq c_i(y)$, whence, by \eqref{CA4},
$$c_i(x) = c_i(x \wedge c_i(y)) = c_i(x) \wedge c_i(y),$$
and therefore $c_i(x) \leq c_i(y)$.
Hence $c_i$ is order-preserving.
Thus, using \eqref{b} and \eqref{CA3}, we obtain,
$$c_i(x \vee y) \leq c_i(c_i(x) \vee c_i(y)) \leq c_i(c_i(x \vee y)) = c_i(x \vee y),$$
and so,
$$c_i(x \vee y) = c_i(c_i(x) \vee c_i(y)).$$
We now prove that $c_i(c_i(x) \vee c_i(y)) = c_i(x) \vee c_i(y)$.
Using the de Morgan laws,
\begin{align}
c_i(c_i(x) \vee c_i(y))
&= c_i(((c_i(x))' \wedge (c_i(y))')')\\
&= c_i((c_i((c_i(x))') \wedge c_i((c_i(y))'))')\tag{by \eqref{g}}
\end{align}
Let $x_1 = (c_i(x))'$ and $y_1 = (c_i(y))'$.
Thus,
\begin{align}
c_i(x \vee y)
&= c_i( ( c_i(x_1) \wedge c_i(y_1) )' )\\
&= c_i( ( c_i(x_1 \wedge c_i(y_1)) )' )\tag{by \eqref{CA4}}\\
&= (c_i( x_1 \wedge c_i(y_1) ))'\tag{by \eqref{g}}\\
&= ( c_i(x_1) \wedge c_i(y_1) )'\tag{by \eqref{CA4}}\\
&= (c_i(x_1))' \vee (c_i(y_1))'\tag{by de Morgan}\\
&= (c_i((c_i(x))'))' \vee (c_i((c_i(y))'))'\\
&= ((c_i(x))')' \vee ((c_i(y))')'\tag{by \eqref{g}}\\
&= c_i(x) \vee c_i(y).\tag{by de Morgan}
\end{align}

---

By the way, to prove \eqref{g}, just show that $c_i((c_i(x))')$ is the complement of $c_i(x)$.
To see that $c_i((c_i(x))') \wedge c_i(x) = 0$, use \eqref{CA4} and the fact that $c_i(0)=0$ (which is (CA2));
to see that $c_i((c_i(x))') \vee c_i(x) = 1$, use \eqref{CA3} and the fact that $(c_i(x))' \vee c_i(x) = 1$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I still wonder whether you can prove this without showing (g), but it seems very hard.

Comment: @user722227 Notice that I claimed in a comment to your post that I also used (f) in the proof, but I didn't. Actually, when revising that solution I found it was wrong in one passage, and I had to come up with a patch. That only made the proof two steps longer, but I suppose that it is possible to get a shorter one. This is just the one I've got. Concerning the usage of (g), notice that we actually only use the axioms. You can see the usage of (g) as a shortcut. But perhaps you meant that the solution of the exercise would be tidier with a linear proof (a)->(i).